# Dismissing a Bootstrap Dialog within an UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Clicking the "Show" button in the example below shows a simple bootstrap modal dialog with two buttons: Cancel (dismissed with data-dismiss), and "OK" which would presumably do some work on the server side, then call a bit of Javascript to hide the dialog.

The basic concept works fine--until I try to wrap the whole thing in an UpdatePanel as shown below. What the devil am I doing wrong? (And for bonus points, how would I attempt to set up a trace through Javascript which would have told me what I'm screwing up?)

Thanks!

**Form Code:**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"
     CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/jquery-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1"
            runat="server" ScriptMode="Debug">
        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <div>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlTestPanel" runat="server" role="dialog" 
                        CssClass="modal fade TestDialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close"
                                        data-dismiss="modal" 
                                        aria-hidden="true">&times;
                                    </button>
                                    <h2 class="modal-title">Test Dialog</h2>
                                </div>

                                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTestBody" 
                                    class="modal-body">
                                    <label>This is a test dialog</label>
                                </asp:Panel>

                                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel3" 
                                    class="modal-footer">
                                    <asp:Button ID="cmdOK" runat="server"
                                        Text="OK" 
                                        CssClass="btn btn-warning">
                                    </asp:Button>&nbsp;

                                    <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server"
                                        CssClass="btn btn-default"
                                        Text="Cancel"
                                        data-dismiss="modal">
                                    </asp:Button>

                                </asp:Panel>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Show" ID="cmdShow" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code-behind code**

```
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub cmdShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdShow.Click
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "pnlTestPanel", _
            "$('#" & pnlTestPanel.ClientID & "').modal();", True)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub cmdOK_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOK.Click
        ' Do some server side work 

        ' And now, close the dialog
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), _
           "Hide Test Dialog", "$('.TestDialog').modal('hide');", True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` will only work when you there is a full PostBack. In your case the PostBack occurs inside an `UpdatePanel`.

You will need to use the JavaScript events that ASP.NET has when an `UpdatePanel` is updated.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    console.log('UpdatePanel start');
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    console.log('UpdatePanel end');
}
```

You need to put your code in the `EndRequestHandler` event to close the modal.

For more info you can [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397432(v=vs.100).aspx) here and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383810(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Even if button is inside an update panel, the script manager will still work as you are passing updatepanel & not the page as its parameter..

There is only one thing missing. 
Write this statement inside your Register startup script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
  $('.TestDialog').modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I found was to create a simple javascript function.

```
    function closeModal(modalid) {
        $('#' + modalid).modal('hide');
    }
```

Then, in your various Modals on the page, you can set a OnClientClick value of the Submit/Create button to "closeModal('id_of_your_modal_container');"

I can then use UpdatePanels with Triggers, as well as all the normal trimmings I want on the page (Toastr notifications etc), and it works very seamlessly. If it's just a standard button or anchor tag then setting a data attribute is all you need 'data-dismiss="modal"'